# Refactoring Javascript code to use Transduction

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have a doubt related to transduction in functional programming
If I have an operation -
`arr.map(A).map(B).filter(C).filter(D).map(E).map(F)`
To remove the intermediate creation of arrays, can I rewrite it as -

```
import _ from "lodash"

const mapReducer = (mapperFn) => (combinerFn) => (acc, val) =>
  combinerFn(acc, mapperFn(val));

const filterReducer = (predicateFn) => (combinerFn) => (acc, val) =>
  predicateFn(val) ? combinerFn(acc, val) : acc;

const push = (arr, x) => { arr.push(x); return arr }

const transducer = _.flowRight(
  mapReducer(_.flowRight(B, A)),
  filterReducer(_.flowRight(D, C)),
  mapReducer(_.flowRight(F, E))
)
arr.reduce(transducer(push), [])
```

Comment: What is the question here? Does the code work or not?

Comment: Afaik, lodash already does avoid intermediate array creation internally

Comment: @Bergi I read about transduction, and through an example wanted to ensure that I got it correct.

Comment: Did you mean to use `push` instead of `_.concat` as the innermost reducer?

Comment: @Bergi yes....but I thought `_.concat` may be more ideal, assuming it's a pure function...

Comment: @keemahs sure it's a pure function but it will create more intermediate arrays. since you're starting with a fresh input, `[]`, it's safe to `.push`. there are no observable side effects in this case if you trade `_.concat` for `(r,x) => { r.push(x); return r }`.

Comment: @keemahs I wasn't concerned so much about purity and temporary arrays, but about the type. `reduce(mapReducer(f)(push), [])` is `map(f)`, whereas `reduce(mapReducer(f)(concat), [])` is `concatMap(f)`, a very different function.

Comment: @Mulan i have changed the code to use push now...

Comment: but @Bergi, that doesnt realy make a difference in my opinion as to what I am trying to achieve....refactoring to use transduction